# Java Class error : java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed

Tags: java, pipe

We are intermittently getting "java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed" with below code. There is very intermittent in nature.  Any advice? I tried to replicate this and when i disconnect my machine from network then i am able to get this error. This class read and write information after Siebel CRM session is open.

Here with Java class code.

```
   private Process _process;
   private OutputStream _processOut;
   private ByteArrayOutputStream _sessionOutput;
....
   _processOut = _process.getOutputStream();
   _sessionOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
....
 public void writeCommand(String command)
   throws IOException
   {
      _processOut.write(command.getBytes());
      _processOut.flush();
      _sessionOutput.write(command.getBytes());

   }
```

Here with Actual error:

```
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:260)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at mySession.writeCommand(mySession.java:169)
```

Answer (score 6):

What is happening is that the external process you are trying to write to has closed the pipe connected to its standard input stream.  It may have just exited.

Try to read and print the processes standard output and standard error to see if they give an explanation as to what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Well it is the case when you have closed the streams and even after that you are trying to write data to streams...

I guess a single stream is handled in 2 threads at where one thread might have closed the stream (may be programatically or by some exception in your stream closing finally block). and the other thread is not notified and trying to write on that stream.